# Sudden drop in speed and altitude?

Tags: flightradar24

Can someone tell me exactly what happened on this flight? It was a brief moment of sudden drop in altitude (6000 feets) almost at the same time with a drop on engine powers. It's a drop of signal from flightradar trackers or an issue recorded in flight? Thank you!

https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/w63655#20da042d

Comment: Definitely a glitch. See the FR24 FAQ.

Comment: What triggers my question is actually the fact that the "glitch" itself is only for altitude on 13:16 and only after 2 other mins it drops on the speed and then recovers (higher speed than the average before) and then temporary drops again (not at the same rate as initially).

Comment: I wouldn't know why a poor signal should be an isolated event.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth descent at 1500 feet per minute from 30,000 to 11,000.  Nothing unusual.
Or was there a blip somewhere in the data that I scrolled past?  (Where?)

**Edit:** The blip at 13:16 is from 36,000 to 29,600 and back, in less than a minute.  A 12,000 fpm dive followed by a 12,000 fpm climb (and vicious G force at the pull-up) is probably impossible for an A320-232.

Comment: Yes there's a blip at/after 13.16 UTC.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm actually reffering to the mid-phase of the flight, 13:16 where there's a sudden drop in altitude and speed.